# How do I format AD MemberOf text file output from Powershell into a ready to copy format for user onboarding?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm still a newbie at Powershell and wanted to create a script to assist with on boarding users at work.

When creating a new user in AD, I want to just quickly copy and paste a list of groups from an existing user, to the new user, when its required they need the same permissions. (Copying User objects in AD is not an option for other reasons.)

So to start with I wrote this for an export of a current user's groups into a text file to copy:

Current code is:

```
#region Variables_Functions_Modules

#Get date

$dateTime = $(get-date -f "yyyy-MM-dd--HH_mm") 

#make directory on c:\
mkdir C:\Scripts -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#define Report Location in variable
$TxtPath = "C:\Scripts"

# Ensures that the PowerShell Snap-ins required by the script are loaded
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#endregion

#region Script Start

$Importname = Read-Host "Please enter in user name"

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Importname | select Name | Out-File "$TxtPath\$Importname $dateTime.txt"

Write-Host "List successfully exported to '$TxtPath\$Importname $dateTime.txt'"  -ForegroundColor Green

#endregion Script End
```

This works well and gives the following example results in a textfile:

---

```
Name
----                                               
Domain Users                                       
Staff_All                                    
All Users                                    
Another Example Group                   
IT                                          
Notifications - NOC
```

---

But it would be better if the groups were formatted like the following, separated with a ; so that I can just copy and paste the results straight into the AD MemberOf tab and press Add, instead of having to do line by line (Some users have a ridiculous amount of groups):

---

```
                                              
Domain Users;Staff_All;All Users;Another Example Group;IT;Notifications - NOC
```

---

I'm not sure on how to manipulate the text in the file into the format I require. I assume the Get-Content would be used to import the file into memory, but not sure how to manipulate the text from there, that has dynamic results with every user, removing the random whitespaces after group names, adding the ; etc.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to export, import and then asssign the groupmemberships, you can do:

```
#Get groupmemberships from user - replace [samaccountname] with the samaccountname of the user you want the retrieve the groupmeberhsips for
$user = get-aduser -Identity [samaccountname] -Properties memberof

#Asssign same groupmemberships to another usser - replace [samaccountname] with the samaccountname of the user you want to assign the groupmemberships to
$null = Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity [samaccountname] -MemberOf $user.memberof

#Or as one liner
get-aduser -Identity [samaccountname] -Properties memberof | %{Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity [samaccountname] -MemberOf $_.memberof}
```